# Why does DSolve give a different result than NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

When I try `DSolve` to solve a system:

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. DSolve[{
    x'[t] == y[t] / 100,
    y'[t] == -100 x[t] - 100 y[t] + 2020,
    x[0] == 0,
    y[0] == 20
}, {x, y}, t]], {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

I get

[image: DSolve]

where `DSolve` gives the solution

```
{{x->Function[{t},-(1/70) E^(-50 t-7 Sqrt[51] t) (707-99 Sqrt[51]+707 E^(14 Sqrt[51] t)+99 Sqrt[51] E^(14 Sqrt[51] t)-1414 E^(14 Sqrt[51] t+(50-7 Sqrt[51]) t))],y->Function[{t},10/7 E^(-50 t-7 Sqrt[51] t) (7-Sqrt[51]+7 E^(14 Sqrt[51] t)+Sqrt[51] E^(14 Sqrt[51] t))]}}
```

$$x(t) = \frac{e^{-7 \sqrt{51} t-50 t}}{70} \times \left(707 e^{14 \sqrt{51} t}+99 \sqrt{51} e^{14 \sqrt{51} t}-1414 e^{\left(50-7 \sqrt{51}\right) t+14 \sqrt{51} t}+707-99 \sqrt{51}\right)$$
$$y(t) = \frac{10}{7} e^{-7 \sqrt{51} t-50 t} \left(7 e^{14 \sqrt{51} t}+\sqrt{51} e^{14 \sqrt{51} t}+7-\sqrt{51}\right)$$

which is a different plot than when I use `NDSolve` to solve the same system:

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == y[t] / 100,
    y'[t] == -100 x[t] - 100 y[t] + 2020,
    x[0] == 0,
    y[0] == 20
}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 50}]], {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

It seems like `DSolve` is incorrect, but why?

Comment: What if you change the `0.01` to `1/100`, and set `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` in `NDSolve[]`?

Comment: @J. M.: Interesting, simply changing `0.01 y[t]` to `y[t]/100` makes `DSolve` match `NDSolve`. Seems like it turns from numeric into symbolic, so I guess that means NDSolve is actually the correct one! Thanks!

Comment: @J. M.: Actually, I see something even more bizarre now. When I extend the time of `DSolve` to `{t,0,20}`, I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fURfF.png) -- why is that?

Comment: Confirmed. On Mma v9 both give the same result (your second plot)

Comment: @belisarius: It's correct even when you extend it to `{t,0,20}`?

Comment: I'll answer that one in the  next comment. Meanwhile the extrapolation  `Plot[Evaluate[
  y[t] /. NDSolve[{x'[t] == 0.01 y[t], 
     y'[t] == -100 x[t] - 100 y[t] + 2020, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 20}, {x,
      y}, {t, 0, .1}]], {t, 0, .5}]` gives [Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FUePS.png)

Comment: And yes.The plots are equal on the `{0,20}` range too

Comment: Interesting. Not sure why Mathematica 10.1 would behave [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MiO9h.png) then.

Comment: I'm quite sure that is related to the title of [this paper](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-471.pdf)

Comment: Please edit your question and post the `DSolve[ ]` result. Just curious.

Comment: @belisarius: I changed the question, see new revision.

Comment: I meant:Please post the OUTPUT (rules) of DSOLVE (not the plot). Sorry

Comment: @belisarius: Ohh I see, okay done.

Comment: Ha! In v9 your first plot doesn't show the discontinuity when using the result (rules) you just posted!

Comment: @belisarius: So it's just a random bug...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like classic catastrophic round-off error. (Look at those exponents on $e$!).

```
{sol} = DSolve[{x'[t] == y[t]/100, 
    y'[t] == -100 x[t] - 100 y[t] + 2020, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 20}, {x, 
    y}, t];
```

Now consider `y[9.]` vs. `y[9]` and `` y[9.`20] ``:

```
y[9.] /. sol
```

> N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating -Sqrt[51]. >>

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
y[9] /. sol // N
(*  18.46310871964039  *)

y[9.`20] /. sol
(*  18.463108719640715  *)
```

Try using a higher working precision:

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]